# Javascript constructor pattern and garbage collector

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, constructor, garbage-collection, durandal

I'm using the following constructor in a Durandal-based SPA. (I've also asked this question in Durandal google group, no response yet).  The Durandal framework is in control of the "new"ing of this viewmodel when the user navigates to the page.

```
function () {

 var ctor = function () {

     this.arr1 = [];
     var arr2 = [];

     this.getData = function () {

         for (i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
             this.arr1.push ({ empName: "mike", empAge: 30, empTitle: 'Senior Software Engineer' });
             arr2.push      ({ empName: "mike", empAge: 30, empTitle: 'Senior Software Engineer' });
         }

         alert("done");
     }      
};

return ctor;
```

});

A button click on the view triggers getData. 
After the arrays are populated and I navigate away, the objects in arr1 are garbage collected. The objects in arr2 are not.

I'm experimenting with using "var" instead of "this" because of some articles I read about creating private variables in this pattern.  Are there downsides to mixing "var" and "this"?

Should the JS GC be cleaning both of these arrays up?  If yes, than I can put more focus on Durandal as having a hand in it.

Testing was done using Profiles in  Chrome Dev Tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The garbage collector will clean up your data whether it's in a local (e.g. private) variable or in an instance variable as soon as the containing object is available for GC.  It does not make a different from that perspective.

Private variables are useful and a perfectly acceptable way to code.  They require that all methods that access them be defined in the constructor like your `.getData()` method is defined.  You cannot use the prototype for methods that want access to private variables defined in the constructor because methods on the prototype are in a different scope.

You can read more about the private member variable design pattern here: http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html

Comment: thanks for the link.  I think it may be a timing issue.  The "this" array was GC'ed immediately.  The "var" array eventually got collected after a while as the app say idle.

Comment: @mwill - GC is is never immediate in JS - it always runs when the interpreter is idle.